# How to get dynamic values by selection (mysql database) in multiple table rows

Tags: javascript, php

I have created an invoice table in which rows are created by pressing 'Add' button. In addition, items price are being displayed into first row of the input value by selection. Everything is fine but when I come to the second row by pressing Add row, price value isn't working by pressing selection.

Here is the table code:

```php
<div class="box pattern pattern-sandstone">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="customFields">
            <tr>
                <td> 1 </td>
                <td>
                    <?php include "db_conn.php"; 
                        $query_order_to = "SELECT * from gs_items ORDER BY item_name ASC";
                        $result_order_to = $conn->query($query_order_to); ?>
                    <select name="selected_item" id="selected_item" onchange="myItemPrice()" data-placeholder="Item Name" >
                        <option value="">Select Item</option>
                        <?php
                            while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_order_to))
                            { ?> 
                        <option data-price='<?php echo $rows['price']; ?>' value='<?php echo $rows['Id']; ?>'> <?php echo $rows['item_name']; ?></option>
                        ";
                        <?php } ?>  
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><textarea style="min-width: 90%;"></textarea></td>
                <td>  <input type="text" name="getprice" style="font-size: 12px; color: #333333;" id="getprice" disabled></td>
                <td><input type="number" ></td>
                <td><input type="number" ></td>
                <td><button onclick="addRow();">Add</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is Javascript + PHP:

```php
<script>
    function findAddress(){
          var address = $('#select_data').find(':selected').data('address');
          $('#getcustomeraddress').val(address);
       }
</script>
<script>
    function myItemPrice(){
          var price = $('#selected_item').find(':selected').data('price');
          $('#getprice').val(price);
       }
</script>
<?php 
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','gs'); 
    function fill_unit_select_box($conn)
    { $query_item = "SELECT * from gs_items ORDER BY item_name ASC";
    $result_item = $conn->query($query_item);
     $x = 1;
    foreach($result_item as $rows)
    {    echo '<option data-prices'.$x++.'="'.$rows['price'].'" value="'.$rows['Id'].'">'.$rows['item_name'].'</option>';
     }
    } ?>
<script>
    function addRow()
    {  var table = document.getElementById("customFields");
    var i = 1;
    while (i <= table.rows.length) {
      i++;
    }
      var html = '';
    html += '<tr>';
    html += '<td >'+i+'</td>';
    html += '<td><select name="selected_items'+i+'" id="selected_items'+i+'" onchange="myItemPrices()" data-placeholder="Item Name" ><option value="">Select Item</option>';
    html += ' <?php echo fill_unit_select_box($conn); ?>
    </select></td>';
      html += '<td > <textarea style="min-width: 90%;"></textarea></td>';
      html +='<td > <input type="number" name="getprices'+i+'" style="font-size: 12px; color: #333333;" id="getprices'+i+'" ></td>';
      html +='<td ><input type="number" ></td>';
       html +='<td ><input type="number" ></td>';
      html +='<td><button onclick="remove();">Remove</button></td>';
      html +='</tr>';
      $('#customFields').append(html);
    }
    function myItemPrices(){
    var prices = $('#selected_items'+i+'').find(':selected').data('prices'+i+'');
         $('#getprices'+i+'').val(prices); }  
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: thefirstthingtodoisindentingyourcodecorrectlysoitbecomesreadable

Comment: You should in some way pass the variable i when you trigger the javascript myItemPrices (right now the value is never passed so it will always update the 1st box, with i = empty)

Comment: @KenLee I tried it but the result was same

Comment: Please see my answer (fully working)

Comment: @KenLee Please check my second questions. All coding are same, just trying to get total value from quantity and price. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69166343/why-i-am-not-getting-total-value-correctly-after-changing-in-item-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed a number of bugs in your original codes

1. The $x++ is not necessary for the function fill_unit_select_box($conn)
2. You should pass the i to the javascript myItemPrices function, for example as var1 (so will be myItemPrices(var1)):

Please find below a fully working one:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="box pattern pattern-sandstone">
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>#</th>
<th>Item</th><th>Description</th><th>Price</th><th>Qty</th><th>Total</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody id="customFields">
<tr>
<td>1</td><td >
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','dbuser','dbpass','dbname'); 

$query_order_to = "SELECT * from gs_items ORDER BY item_name ASC";
$result_order_to = $conn->query($query_order_to); ?>
<select name="selected_item" id="selected_item" onchange="myItemPrice()" data-placeholder="Item Name" >
<option value="">Select Item</option>
<?php
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_order_to))
{ ?> <option data-price='<?php echo $rows['price']; ?>' value='<?php echo $rows['Id']; ?>'> <?php echo $rows['item_name']; ?></option>";
<?php } ?>  </select> </td>
<td ><textarea style="min-width: 90%;"></textarea></td>
<td ><input type="text" name="getprice" style="font-size: 12px; color: #333333;" id="getprice" disabled></td>
<td ><input type="number" ></td>
<td ><input type="number" ></td>
<td><button onclick="addRow();">Add</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>


<script>
 function findAddress(){
       var address = $('#select_data').find(':selected').data('address');
       $('#getcustomeraddress').val(address);
    }
</script>

<script>
 function myItemPrice(){
       var price = $('#selected_item').find(':selected').data('price');
       $('#getprice').val(price);
    }
</script>

<?php 

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','dbuser','dbpass','dbname'); 


function fill_unit_select_box($conn)
{ 
$query_item = "SELECT * from gs_items ORDER BY item_name ASC";
$result_item = $conn->query($query_item);
 $x = 1;
foreach($result_item as $rows)
{    echo '<option data-prices="'.$rows['price'].'" value="'.$rows['Id'].'">'.$rows['item_name'].'</option>';
 }
} ?>
<script>
  function addRow()
  {  var table = document.getElementById("customFields");
var i = 0;
while (i <= table.rows.length) {
    i++;
 }
i=i-1; 
    var html = '';
  html += '<tr>';
  html += '<td >'+i+'</td>';
  html += '<td><select name="selected_items'+i+'" id="selected_items'+i+'" onchange="myItemPrices(' + i +')" data-placeholder="Item Name" ><option value="">Select Item</option>';
  html += ' <?php echo fill_unit_select_box($conn); ?>
  </select></td>';
    html += '<td > <textarea style="min-width: 90%;"></textarea></td>';
    html +='<td ><input type="text" disabled name="getprices'+i+'" style="font-size: 12px; color: #333333;" id="getprices'+i+'" ></td>';
    html +='<td ><input type="number" ></td>';
     html +='<td ><input type="number" ></td>';
    html +='<td><button onclick="remove();">Remove</button></td>';
    html +='</tr>';
    $('#customFields').append(html);
  }




 function myItemPrices(var1){
 i=var1;
 var prices = $('#selected_items'+i+'').find(':selected').data('prices');
 $('#getprices'+i+'').val(prices); }  

   </script>
```

[image]

Comment: I am very grateful to you for solving my question very well. Thank You @KenLee

Comment: You are welcome. Have a nice day and Happy Coding.