# Why I am not getting total value correctly after changing in item name?

Tags: javascript, php

I am new in Javascript. I have created an invoice table where the total value in the last column is calculated by selecting item price with putting the value in quantity field.

There are two issues being faced by me.

1. The total value is calculated correctly when I put the value in the quantity but total value isn't updating the correct total when I change item name.
   [image: issue111]
2. The total value isn't reflecting, when I set the type of input i.e type="number" and try to add value by arrow

[image: issue222]

Here is the Code:

```
<div class="box pattern pattern-sandstone">
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>#</th>
<th>Item</th><th>Description</th><th>Price</th><th>Qty</th><th>Total</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody id="customFields">
<tr>
<td>1</td><td >
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','dbuser','dbpass','dbname'); 

$query_order_to = "SELECT * from gs_items ORDER BY item_name ASC";
$result_order_to = $conn->query($query_order_to); ?>
<select name="selected_item" id="selected_item" onchange="myItemPrice()" data-placeholder="Item Name" >
<option value="">Select Item</option>
<?php
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_order_to))
{ ?> <option data-price='<?php echo $rows['price']; ?>' value='<?php echo $rows['Id']; ?>'> <?php echo $rows['item_name']; ?></option>";
<?php } ?>  </select> </td>
<td ><textarea style="min-width: 90%;"></textarea></td>
<td >  <input type="text" name="getprice"  id="getprice" readonly></td>
<td ><input type="number" id="qty" onKeyUp="multiply()" input-number></td>
<td ><input  type="text" id="total" readonly></td>
<td><button onclick="addRow();">Add</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>


<script>
 function findAddress(){
       var address = $('#select_data').find(':selected').data('address');
       $('#getcustomeraddress').val(address);
    }
</script>

<script>
 function myItemPrice(){
       var price = $('#selected_item').find(':selected').data('price');
       $('#getprice').val(price);
    }
</script>

<?php 

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','dbuser','dbpass','dbname'); 


function fill_unit_select_box($conn)
{ 
$query_item = "SELECT * from gs_items ORDER BY item_name ASC";
$result_item = $conn->query($query_item);
 $x = 1;
foreach($result_item as $rows)
{    echo '<option data-prices="'.$rows['price'].'" value="'.$rows['Id'].'">'.$rows['item_name'].'</option>';
 }
} ?>
<script>
  function addRow()
  {  var table = document.getElementById("customFields");
var i = 0;
while (i <= table.rows.length) {
    i++;
 }
i=i-1; 
    var html = '';
  html += '<tr>';
  html += '<td >'+i+'</td>';
  html += '<td><select name="selected_items'+i+'" id="selected_items'+i+'" onchange="myItemPrices(' + i +')" data-placeholder="Item Name" ><option value="">Select Item</option>';
  html += ' <?php echo fill_unit_select_box($conn); ?>
  </select></td>';
    html += '<td > <textarea style="min-width: 90%;"></textarea></td>';
    html +='<td ><input type="text" disabled name="getprices'+i+'" style="font-size: 12px; color: #333333;" id="getprices'+i+'" ></td>';
    html +='<td ><input type="number" ></td>';
     html +='<td ><input type="number" ></td>';
    html +='<td><button onclick="remove();">Remove</button></td>';
    html +='</tr>';
    $('#customFields').append(html);
  }
 function myItemPrices(var1){
 i=var1;
 var prices = $('#selected_items'+i+'').find(':selected').data('prices');
 $('#getprices'+i+'').val(prices); }  

   </script>

<script>
function multiply() {
  a = Number(document.getElementById('qty').value);
  b = Number(document.getElementById('getprice').value);
  c = a * b;

  document.getElementById('total').value = c;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Your total is the result of adding many items. If you change the Qty of any one row in the table you will have to add them all up again as you dont know what the OldQty was before you changed it, so you dont know what the subtract from total before adding the new qty*price to the total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several tries to find the solution, Finally I got the answer:

```
 <script>
     function myItemPrice(){
           var price = $('#selected_item').find(':selected').data('price');
           $('#getprice').val(price);
           var getprice = document.getElementsByName('getprice')[0].value;
          var qty = document.getElementsByName('qty')[0].value;
          var total;
         total = parseFloat(getprice) * parseFloat(qty);
          document.getElementsByName('total')[0].value = total;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Just waked up. Good to know that you've fixed the problem by yourself.